# Can we restrict apk reverse engineering(de-complication) using Android Application Licensing for free apps without apk expansion?.

Tags: android, google-play

I gone through https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html. **they mentioned Licensing for paid & Apk expansion free apps**.

Answer (score 0):

I use Dexprotector , It not Free but Works https://dexprotector.com/